# How ViewModel can observe a list? MediatorLiveData onChange never called

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata, android-lifecycle

I want to launch a CoroutineScope to start loading data from the database during the splash screen so the main activity can show the data quickly, but I don't want to delay the splash screen to wait for the results (It is a good practice?).

When the Main activity sets up the UI with an observer of the ViewModel list, call the ViewModel `loadList()` so it can get the list loaded by the Repository and post the value, so the observer gets triggered.
But the repository works on a different thread and ViewModel can request the data first of repository can fill it.
So I need to trigger the ViewModel when the repository loads the data from the database

This is the code of SplashScreen:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    //this class load the data from database
    PersistenceSingleton.getInstance(application)

    startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
    finish()
}
```

PersistenceSingleton:

```
private var dbAccess: PersistenceSingletonRepository? = null // Singleton
private lateinit var db: PokemonDatabase
var listOfPokemon: MutableLiveData<MutableList<Pokemon>> = MutableLiveData()

fun getInstance(context: Context) = synchronized(this){
    if (dbAccess == null) {
        dbAccess = PersistenceSingleton()
        db = PokemonDatabase.getInstance(context)
        //load all pokemon
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val lan = Locale.getDefault().language
             val list = if (lan.equals("it")) {
                db.pokemonDao().loadAllPokemonIt()
             } else {
                db.pokemonDao().loadAllPokemon()
             }
             CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                listOfPokemon.value = list
             }
        }
    }
    dbAccess
}
```

ViewModel:

```
var pokemonList: MutableLiveData<MutableList<Pokemon>> = MutableLiveData()

fun loadLists() {
    //list could be empty. ViewModel need to observe the list on PersistenceSingleton (Repository)
    pokemonList.value = PersistenceSingleton.listOfPokemon.value
}
```

Main activity setUI:

```
private fun setUI() {
    val observer = Observer<List<Pokemon>> { list ->
        if (list != null) {
            //hide progress bar  and set recycler view adapter
            binding.pbPokemonlist.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

            adapter = PokemonListAdapter(list)
            binding.rvPokemon.adapter = adapter
        }
    }
    pokemonListVM.pokemonList.observe(this, observer)
    //inflate the recycler view
    pokemonListVM.loadLists()
}
```

**Edit**

To make the ViewModel an observer I used `MediatorLiveData`, so my new ViewModel:

```
var pokemonList: MutableLiveData<MutableList<Pokemon>> = MutableLiveData()
private val pokemonListMediator: MediatorLiveData<List<Pokemon>> = MediatorLiveData()

init {
    val observer = Observer<MutableList<Pokemon>> { list ->
        Log.d("POKEMON", "onChange")
        pokemonList.value = list
    }
    pokemonListMediator.addSource(PersistenceSingletonRepository.listOfPokemon, observer)
}

//load full list of Pokemon
fun loadLists() {
    //list could be empty. ViewModel need to observe the list on PersistenceSingleton (Repository)
    pokemonList.value = PersistenceSingletonRepository.listOfPokemon.value
}
```

But observer `onChange()` is never called

Comment: Why even have a splash screen at all if the screen doesn't contain any logic? The better way is to use a [background drawable](https://medium.com/android-news/right-way-to-create-splash-screen-on-android-e7f1709ba154). Then, you just load the data from the main screen and display a loading indicator while the loading is occurring.

Comment: The splash screen layout is declared on Manifest using themes

Answer (score 0):

You could place both `Lists` inside the `ViewModel` and make them `MutableLiveData`.

You would start to `observe` both `MutableLiveData` objects inside the `onCreate` function in your `Activity`.

After you have done the bare minimum of set up call `loadLists` inside the `onCreate`. (Like getting a `RecyclerView` and setting its `Adapter` so your data has somewhere to go)

Your `loadList` function should look kinda like this

```
       public var pokemonList: MutableLiveData<List<Pokemon>> = MutableLiveData()
       public var typeList : MutableLiveData<List<Type>> = MutableLiveData() 
       fun loadLists(context: Context) {
            db = PokemonDatabase.getInstance(context)
            //separate CoroutineScope for each database call
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                pokemonList.postValue(db.pokemonDao().loadAllPokemon())
            }
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO.launch{
                typeList.postValue(db.pokemonDao().loadAllType())
            }
        }
```

Your `OnCreate` should have this

```
    mainViewModel.pokemonList.observe(this, Observer { pokemans ->
       //something like this
       pokemonAdapter.list = pokemans
    })
    mainViewModel.typeList.observe(this, Observer { types->
       //something like this
       typeAdapter.list = types
    })
```

With this your data should come to you quite quickly, anything more complicated will hurt you later.

EDIT: To go with your edit.

You're almost there, you just need another callback I'll use the

`androidx.lifecycle.Observer<T>` for brevity.

```
PersistenceSingleton.getInstance(getApplication())!!.getListOfPokemon(
 Observer<List<Pokemon>> { pokemon ->{
       pokemonList.postValue(pokemon)
 }
)
```

And then in your `getListOfPokemon` function

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    observer.onChanged(db.pokemonDao().loadAllPokemon())
}
```

This will return a list of pokemon when and only when its available. And you wont have to worry about a null list of pokemon, as nothing is ever emitted until there is actual data.

Comment: I know, this is a clear way to make this work but I don't like that ViewModel needs to launch a CoroutineScope for launching a DAO method. Only the repository should get the data from the database. So in my case, the problem is to notify the ViewModel when the repository gets the data.  I will try to be more specific in the question

Comment: Oh, I deleted the function getListOfPokemon() because I let public the listOfPokemon. But why get another call to the Dao in getListOfPokemon() if they are already loaded? It is useless to do all this stuff if I need to reload the data from database

Comment: getListOfPokemon could just immediately use the given observer if the stored list already has the pokemon  instead of pulling it again, if it is empty it gets it from the DAO and use the observer like in my answer.

Comment: The purpose of this is that a PersistanceSingleton that is a repository try to load all the data as soon as possible, then when a View needs call the ViewModel to get the data. If ViewModel has the data all is fine, otherwise the ViewModel wait the data